# Keras ValueError: Shapes (256, 652) and (256, 64) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement a neural network based upon [this link](https://towardsdatascience.com/music-genre-classification-transformers-vs-recurrent-neural-networks-631751a71c58) using fma-small dataset.
I completed.csv and dataset .npy jobs done, but when I try to start learning, it gives me

```
    _________________________________________________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/music_genre_classification-master/code/rnn_genre_classification.py", line 38, in <module>
    model.load_weights(h5_name)
  File "C:\miniconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 181, in load_weights
    return super(Model, self).load_weights(filepath, by_name)
  File "C:\miniconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 1177, in load_weights
    saving.load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f, self.layers)
  File "C:\miniconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py", line 699, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group
    K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)
  File "C:\miniconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py", line 3343, in batch_set_value
    x.assign(np.asarray(value, dtype=dtype(x)))
  File "C:\miniconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 814, in assign
    self._shape.assert_is_compatible_with(value_tensor.shape)
  File "C:\miniconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 1115, in assert_is_compatible_with
    raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))
ValueError: Shapes (256, 652) and (256, 64) are incompatible
```

Codes below are model definition:

```
def rnn_classifier(
    d_model=128, n_layers=2, n_classes=16,
):
    inp = Input((None, d_model))

    x = Bidirectional(GRU(d_model, return_sequences=True))(inp)

    if n_classes > 1:
        for i in range(n_layers - 1):
            x = Bidirectional(GRU(d_model, return_sequences=True))(x)

    x = Dropout(0.2)(x)

    x = GlobalAvgPool1D()(x)

    x = Dense(4 * n_classes, activation="selu")(x)

    out = Dense(n_classes, activation="sigmoid")(x)

    model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)

    opt = Adam(0.00001)

    model.compile(
        optimizer=opt, loss=custom_binary_crossentropy, metrics=[custom_binary_accuracy]
    )

    model.summary()

    return model
```

And below is printed properties:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, None, 128)]       0         
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional (Bidirectional (None, None, 256)         198144    
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_1 (Bidirection (None, None, 256)         296448    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, None, 256)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling1d (Gl (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 652)               167564    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 163)               106439    
=================================================================
Total params: 768,595
Trainable params: 768,595
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I followed guide just exactly except using fma_large dataset and some relative paths edit.

I'm using pycharm with miniconda and all library required in this project(tensorflow 2.0.1 and else).

It is right to upload the code that has been minimally organized, but the original text of the code where the problem occurred is as follows:

```
import json
from glob import glob

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau

from models import rnn_classifier
from prepare_data import get_id_from_path, DataGenerator

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from collections import Counter

    h5_name = "rnn.h5"
    batch_size = 32
    epochs = 50
    CLASS_MAPPING = json.load(open("./media/ml/data_ml/fma_metadata/mapping.json"))
    id_to_genres = json.load(open("./media/ml/data_ml/fma_metadata/tracks_genre.json"))
    id_to_genres = {int(k): v for k, v in id_to_genres.items()}

    base_path = "./media/ml/data_ml/fma_small"
    files = sorted(list(glob(base_path + "/*/*.npy")))
    files = [x for x in files if id_to_genres[int(get_id_from_path(x))]]
    labels = [id_to_genres[int(get_id_from_path(x))] for x in files]
    print(len(labels))

    samples = list(zip(files, labels))

    strat = [a[-1] for a in labels]
    cnt = Counter(strat)
    strat = [a if cnt[a] > 2 else "" for a in strat]

    train, val = train_test_split(
        samples, test_size=0.2, random_state=1337, stratify=strat
    )

    model = rnn_classifier(n_classes=len(CLASS_MAPPING))

    model.load_weights(h5_name)

    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
        h5_name,
        monitor="val_loss",
        verbose=1,
        save_best_only=True,
        mode="min",
        save_weights_only=True,
    )
    reduce_o_p = ReduceLROnPlateau(
        monitor="val_loss", patience=20, min_lr=1e-7, mode="min"
    )

    model.fit_generator(
        DataGenerator(train, batch_size=batch_size, class_mapping=CLASS_MAPPING),
        validation_data=DataGenerator(
            val, batch_size=batch_size, class_mapping=CLASS_MAPPING
        ),
        epochs=epochs,
        callbacks=[checkpoint, reduce_o_p],
        use_multiprocessing=True,
        workers=12,
        verbose=2,
        max_queue_size=64,
    )
```

Comment: Could you show us some more code so that we can understand the problem better?

Comment: I added original codes that I'm getting problems

Comment: please note that tf.fit_generator is depreciated. Use model.fit instead. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit_generator

Comment: it seems you are loading a pre trained model judging by the first line in the error message. If the data you feed the network changes then you need to train from scratch. Can you try not loading a pre-trained model?

Comment: This repo does not contain a pre-learned model, but I created the h5 file using model.save_weights(). I'm not the original author, so I lack of understanding the model-loading part.

Comment: I tried to change model's metrics from binary to sparse, and changed depreciated expressions to model.fit but it comes out with same error.